# What are these wires on the side of the SLS core stage?

Tags: rockets, sls

I was [reading about the SLS core being moved for testing](https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/01/boeing-finally-completes-sls-core-stage-packs-it-for-mississippi-tests/) and I noticed something odd on the core stage. There's several lines on the stage, which in closer inspection are wires. It's not obvious what they are, since they form several circles on the core stage. Does anyone know what they do?

[image: SLS Core]

Comment: A total guess - strain gauges?

Comment: wiring harness for various sensors I'd imagine, the loops probably being temporary, where they leave the core to attach to the infrastructure (I'd say it's way to thick for the loops to be strain gauges, you want those as thin as possible)